# How can i use exclude to refactor my function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to refactor my function **(i dont want to use each, i want to solve in only 1 line)**, so far i am using .each but i was wondering if is posible to do more brief? that function its about that if v doest not belong to address array then i should return false, other case return true

```
address = %w[one two]
result = true
types.each do |_, v|
      result = false if address.exclude?(v)
end
```

note: currently my function is working well

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Comment: @max i dont want to use each, i want to solve in only 1 line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are all the values included in the address list?

```
types.values.all? { |val| address.include?(v) }
```

Or, alternatively:

```
(types.values - address).none?
```

(you could also use `.empty?`, `.length == 0`, etc instead of `none?` here).